# Google Sheet script finding given URL in page source

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for a Google sheet script which is able to check is given URL in page source or not.

Something similar to this formula "=IMPORTXML(URL,"//h1")" which is exporting headings from page.

I just need something like this but checking given URL

If you know is it is doable, but it will take much time, I can pay for this.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this formula**
[***Make a copy***](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tnj7LFYsHLloVOzkdGiQcHuHa0J4dQYOlWfCdfoz0EE/copy) of this sheet.

```
=IF(ISTEXT(IMPORTXML(A2,"//h1"))=TRUE,"Source","Not a source")
```

[image]